# PG:ConnectBad Rails 4 Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-postgresql

I know it seems like this question has been asked a hundred times but this time I think it is different.

When I restart my mac and run rails s, the site works fine.

```
➜  BankingApp git:(master) ✗ which psql
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql
➜  BankingApp git:(master) ✗ which postgres
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/postgres
```

But when I restart the server, it gives this error every time.

I am using osx mountain lion and Postgres.app. I am also using omyzsh which uses .zshrc. In that file I have:

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
export PGHOST=localhost
```

I also have Postgres.app running.

Database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: BankingApp
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

If I open the database with PGAdmin 3, I can select from tables etc. It seems to be working. I think there must be a rogue process that is giving this error.

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and                 accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Rails.root: /Users/jod/BankingApp
```

Trace:

```
activerecord (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:796:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:796:in `new'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:796:in `connect'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:513:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
/Users/jod/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: BankingApp
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
```

This fixed the problem!